# Fluent in Portuguese? Apply to be a Community Manager!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-managers

We mentioned this in [Shog9's blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/05/welcome-tim-post-our-latest-community-manager/) officially welcoming Tim Post as a full time CM, but we wanted to get the word out:

**We're looking for Community Manager candidates:**

- **With at least some programming experience or training**
- **Who are fluent in written Portuguese and English.**

That sound like you? Apply [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring/community-manager-bilingual-english-portuguese) today.

Some folks inquired as to *why* we need this. We've long had a backlog of proposals in Area 51 for sites that are (non-English) language specific, and as we continue to work on localization, we need to start building up the community team with individuals who speak languages that are native to a large number of potential users (Brazil, Japan, etc.)

As always, our ideal candidates are folks like you who already grok our system, but if you have friends or colleagues with outside community management skills who speak Portuguese, feel free to share the listing with them.

Note that the role is not going to be limited to covering a future Portuguese-language site.  We're hiring someone who will function like our current CMs do now, but will be able to be a primary contact who's fluent in the language when we are ready to roll out Portuguese site(s) in the future.

Comment: Sounds interesting. When you reach Hebrew, give me a call :)

Comment: Don't you need the same thing in french ^_^.

Comment: The devil on my shoulder told me to flag this NARQ

Comment: Flagging as spam.

Comment: @Flexo and now, at long last, we know the _real_ reason why NARQ was removed from the close reason list on MSO.

Comment: How about Canadian?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, appreciate the thought, but we already have [more Canadians](http://stackexchange.com/users/37099/anna-lear) than we know what to do with.

Comment: @user414076: This is the opposite of spam! They want to give _you_ money. Spam would be "Is your Portuguese sad and lacking? Improve its extent to impress your community!"

Comment: I totally speak Portuguese. It's that language with the throaty sounds, right?

Comment: Hmmm... [I wonder why they want *that*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Aboot time they catered to users that speak nothing but Canadian, eh?

Comment: @Asad you must have maple syruped my hockey mind!

Comment: Shouldn't you have asked this question in Portuguese as well?  Maybe?

Comment: @JoshDM I know, they should totally hire someone who speaks Portuguese to deal with stuff like ... wait.

Comment: I have a [friend](http://translate.google.com) who may be interested :P

Comment: On a more serious note, won't this be hard to scale up if/when we get more such sites?

Comment: [status-completed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/introducing-gabe-the-smiling-community-manager)?

Comment: @gilles, done.  :)

Comment: @Manishearth I think they wont be going beyond any of the [top 10  languages with most native speakers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers#World_Factbook_.E2.80.93_CIA.5B1.5D). Although, I am surprised that Portuguese took higher priority than [Mandarin](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress)

Comment: @AsheeshR More high rep Portuguese programmers on SO supporting the site, IIRC. Also, 10 new CMs is still a lot :p

Comment: @Manishearth Not 10, only 8 new CMs :) That too, if we consider a Hindi or Bengali SE site going up anytime in the future.

Comment: @AsheeshR Or, just hire Alenanno and be done with it :P

Comment: @Manishearth That sounds like another [meta-tag:feature-request] :P

Answer (score 15):

This was [the guy we were looking for](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/introducing-gabe-the-smiling-community-manager/):

[image]

Comment: It would be a lot easier next time if you just post the picture in the question. Makes finding them far easier.

Comment: @bart, we didn't want to waste your time, as the one we had was *super* low-res; we've just now gotten the technology to "enhance it" sufficiently to be of any use.

Comment: I used to be that guy.

Comment: @Gabe: You know we haven't hired Mario yet.  I guess it has something to do with salary demands...

Comment: @Gabe curious to know if the picture was taken before, after or during your recruitment to SE? :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Way before. These days I'm all 1000-yard stare.